# Dashed lines ovelay with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When trying to plot multiple dashed lines over the same dashed line in `pgfplots`, the dashing mismatches, and draws a full line, is there any way to circumvent this?

MVE
left; drawn with `pgfplots`, right; drawn with `tikz` (I want the `tikz` effect with the easiness of `pgfplots`)

Returns this

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.txt}
        a       b
        1       0
        0       1
        0       0
        1       0
        0       1
        1       0
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[mark={}]
                \addplot [dashed] table [x=a,y=b]{test.txt};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[dashed] (1,0) -- (0,1) -- (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) --(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's just a matter of scale and coincidence, I suppose. Set `width=7.1cm` (for example) for the `axis`, and you don't get full overlap, but add `[scale=1.201]` for the second `tikzpicture` and you do get the overlap there.  You could also add `dash phase=1pt` to the `\addplot` options in the `pgfplots` case to remove (most of) the overlap. But none of these are general solutions.

Comment: Is there a way to find the optimal dash phase? I want to plot a unit cell (no the MWE), and i have 2 or three overlapping lines, with the overlapping being different for all cases (although theres a 3d distance of 1 between all points). I tried designing my own dashdotted line, but still get some overlap.

Comment: Tried setting the `dash phase=2pt` for my unit cell, and it looks great, thanks a lot. Would however love for some way of doing this automaticly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not a general, automatic solution, it's possible to play around with the `dash phase` or custom `dash pattern`s, to avoid (at least most of) the overlapping.

[image: output of code]

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.txt}
        a       b
        1       0
        0       1
        0       0
        1       0
        0       1
        1       0
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[mark={}]
      \addplot [dashed,dash phase=1pt] table [x=a,y=b]{test.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[mark={}]
      \addplot [dash pattern=on 0pt off 1pt on 5.68pt] table [x=a,y=b]{test.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I will accept it for now, but should someone come with a answer that works for the general case I will unaccept your answer and accept theirs.

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Of course.

Comment: I was just being precarious; I would feel bad if i unaccepted your answer without letting you know why, and I thought that I might forget to make the comment if I ever saw a general answer.

Comment: Oh wait, just noticed the dash pattern you made starts with 0pt what does this do?

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Ehm, just something weird I happened to try. Looking more closely at the result, I'm not entirely sure exactly what it does ...

Comment: Fair enough, i was just curious if it might be the secret sauce.